# How to programmatically show drop down list of Navigation Controller on iPad?

Tags: objective-c, ios

My landscape-mode only iPad app has a drop-down list as part of a Navigation Controller and I'd like to programmatically show the list at startup rather than waiting for the user to click the button at the top. How can I do that?

Comment: We need code if you want an example. Your description is currently too vague. At least tell us what class the drop-down is! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
-(IBAction)togglePopOverController {
 
if ([popOverController isPopoverVisible]) {
 
[popOverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
 
} else {
 
[popOverController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:bbiOpenPopOver permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
 
}
 
}
```